# ReactSelect Input box width is not calculating correctly

Tags: react-select

As I type text into the box, the text moves left cutting off the left part. If I tab out of the box and return to it, the right part is cut off too.

A codesandbox of it is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/stop-indoctrination-q2gcy)

It used to work fine and I have compared an old version side by side with the current one. If I type the same words into each, the `style.width` of each one is different. For example, if I type "abcdefg" into both apps, the `style.width` of the old version is 74px and the `style.width` in the new version is only 62px. The code that computes this width is [here](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-input-autosize/blob/master/src/AutosizeInput.js#L108) in react-input-autosize and the value of `this.sizer.scrollWidth` is different between the good version and bad version of my app. I just can't tell what's causing it to be different.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the width is calculated based on a hidden div. The hidden's div is populated with the same text as the value you enter in the textbox.

The overflow of this is set to `scroll` and then the width is calculated for the same.

Now this width is dependent on the `font-size`. The `font-size` for the text has been probably changed by you for the search text box, but the `font-size` for sizer is still the same and that is why the issue. When I correct the size manually it works fine

[image: Working]

I have not digged into the CSS to check where you have done the changes, but this should be good enough for you to correct the issue

Comment: Thanks. I don't entirely totally understand why but moving the font-size=20px from the containing element to the input, option and placeholder components of the react-select fixed it. I also tried setting it for the selectContainer and control components of the react-select but that didn't work. The visible input element was inheriting this value but the hidden sizer element was getting the wrong value, 16px. I can't tell where it was getting "16px" in the new, broken version.

Comment: In the library `var inputStyles = this.input && window.getComputedStyle(this.input);`
and after that `copyStyles(inputStyles, this.sizer);` is used to copy the style from the input textbox

Comment: I saw that but I couldn't find the "16px" font-size anywhere. The visible input was "20px". The hidden sizer was "16px". It's okay. As long as it works now I'm fine.

Answer (score 0):

For me fixing the css with important solve the issue, I know it is not the best practice but it worked.

In my case, there was some font overriding the general style of the app but the component input. I fixed like this:

```
.multi-selct-async__input > div, multi-selct-async__input > input {
  font-size: inherit !important;
  font-family: inherit: !important;
}
```

With this change, now the calculations for the width works as expected.